# Windows Store App loading library at runtime xaml error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm loading a library from a Windows Store app through reflection (Activator.CreateInstance), but when the InitializeComponent() for the Page class being loaded dynamically is called I get an exception of "unspecified error".
There are no dots in the assembly name loaded and I've placed the xaml in the correct place specified by the uri in the code behind. I'm using Visual Studio update 3.
I have searched extensively the internet and I haven't any clues what's the problem.
The only strange thing I noticed is that after the loadcomponent() is called the debugger goes through the XamlTypeInfo.g.cs code of the main assembly and not the one of the assembly being loaded, may be that's the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because winrt xaml needs XamlMetadataProvider which is autogenerated and resides in the dynamically loaded assembly in my case.
For a good explanation see:
http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2013/05/30/Decoding-the-IXamlMetadataProvider-interface-Part-1.aspx